# Is there any limitation in train algorithm of R?

Tags: r, memory-management, machine-learning, classification, r-caret

I am using R (RStudio Version 0.98.1017) to train a binary classifier using Naive Bayes algorithm and do a 5-fold cross validation. Here is the code I am using:

```
library(caret)
dataset <- read.table("dataFile.csv", header=TRUE, sep = ",")
attributes = dataset[,-3]
labels = as.factor(dataset$Class)
model = train(attributes, labels, method='nb', trControl=trainControl(method='repeatedcv', number=5))
confusionMatrixResults<-table(predict(model$finalModel,attributes)$class,labels)
confusionMatrix(confusionMatrixResults)
```

Here is a sample data of dataFile.csv file (only first 10 lines):

```
firstName,lastName,Class
ayah,salat,0
abdulahi,youssif,1
yara,abshir,0
sawda,alanazi,1
abubaker,farah,1
yusaira,aden,1
mohammad,okash,0
farhia,alossehy,1
mais,alom,0
```

**The code works perfectly fine if the file contains 2001 lines** (1 header and 2000 records) and it generates the following confusion matrix and results:

```
        labels
      0   1
  0 991   2
  1  17 990

               Accuracy : 0.9905          
                 95% CI : (0.9852, 0.9943)
    No Information Rate : 0.504           
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2.2e-16       

                  Kappa : 0.981           
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.001319        

            Sensitivity : 0.9831          
            Specificity : 0.9980          
         Pos Pred Value : 0.9980          
         Neg Pred Value : 0.9831          
             Prevalence : 0.5040          
         Detection Rate : 0.4955          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.4965          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.9906          

       'Positive' Class : 0
```

But if I add even only 1 extra line, it will generate very poor results (No errors or warnings though):

```
  labels
      0   1
  0 596  78
  1 413 914

               Accuracy : 0.7546          
                 95% CI : (0.7352, 0.7733)
    No Information Rate : 0.5042          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2.2e-16       

                  Kappa : 0.5106          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : < 2.2e-16       

            Sensitivity : 0.5907          
            Specificity : 0.9214          
         Pos Pred Value : 0.8843          
         Neg Pred Value : 0.6888          
             Prevalence : 0.5042          
         Detection Rate : 0.2979          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.3368          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.7560          

       'Positive' Class : 0
```

My question is: How is it possible that one additional record lead to such a different results.
It worth to mention that I have tried couple of random tests with different records and in all of them the problem was independent to a specific record and it occurred when the files had more than 2001 lines.

My guess is that there must be some limitations in regard to memory size, or the Naive Bayes library.

Here is the file if you want to try it (I renamed the attributes to keep them confidential):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7z39wzxilblo2bm/dataFile.csv
removing the last line will improve the results significantly!

Comment: What is the one extra line? It is extremely unlikely that this is memory related.

Comment: It's exactly like one of the lines I currently listed. A first name, last name and a 0/1. And I ran couple of tests which sorted lines randomly. The problem always occurs when the lines are more than 2001!

Comment: Can you link to the full file so that we can verify what you're seeing?

Comment: I really wanted to do so, but unfortunately the company's policy is to consider this list of first and last names confidential, because they are patients names.

Comment: Unless you can provide some data the reproduces the problem (perhaps substitute the names with random strings?) it is unlikely that anyone can help.

Comment: It is almost sure that you are doing something wrong. Include whole code you are using and minimal working example of data. In fact, your first results (acc over 90%) on such data is nearly **impossible**, unless your data is extremely redundant (you have multiple, naerly identical rows)

Comment: Joran, Thank you very much for your comments. I edited the post and provided a link to the data.

Comment: lejlot, The results seem very high, I agree. But it is correct because I have tested the same corpus with Weka as well and I received the same very good results.

Comment: Running your code on your example data generates many warnings for me using either 2000 or 2001 rows, and then the final two confusion matrix lines do not run at all.

Comment: It runs on my computer with no warning or error. Could you please let me know what kind of warnings do you get?